# Best practice for adding other language files in ruby project

Tags: ruby, jar, rubygems

I have a ruby project written purely in ruby. Now I want to include a java archive (jar) file which has some functionality my users want. It is good to just place the file in one of the directories and bundle as a gem? Are there any security issues related to this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you planning on integrating the jar file? Have you considered using [jRuby](http://jruby.org/), which lets you interface with Java APIs?

Comment: This jar file is related to jenkins command line interface. I will not be integrating it with my code. I will just shell out the command line options by specifying the "java -jar #{base_dir}/jenkins-cli.jar ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on the use case.

If this is a gem that users will be using purely for their own purposes, and it's not broadcasting over a network, then security issues are fairly minimal - they would relate more to system security.

If part of your program involves binding to a port and accepting TCP/UDP connections then you've got to really start thinking about network security. Another possible problem is if you're giving file system access to non-privileged users (e.g. if this is a rails gem, and the JAR gives functionality to manipulate the file system and for some reason you're passing this on to the site users - bit of a stupid example but I hope you see what I'm getting at).

However, as for running a java JAR file, there's nothing innately insecure about that unless there are known security flaws with that particular JAR.

In the end, it's up to the end-user of the gem. Make it clear what the gem does and they can make the decision about whether they want to use it.